# Intersections of two curves in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology

Suppose i have two curves $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$, where one is a linear curve,
$$\gamma_1(t)=tP_1+(1-t)P_2$$
and the other is a similar path, composed with a $C^\infty$-diffeomorphism $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$:
$$\gamma_2(t)=\Phi(tP_3+(1-t)P_4)$$

Can one prove, that the intersections are finite closed intervals, where I consider $[a,a] = {a} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ a closed interval as well?

Comment: Do you consider a finite set of points to be a finite closed interval?

Comment: @AlexM. Yes :) sorry i should have mentioned that

Comment: If the diffeo is only C^1 this looks false.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez good point. i want a $C^\infty$-diffeomorphism. i dont know, how i failed to mention that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's wrong. First consider the curve
$$ \gamma(t) = \begin{cases}  (t,0) & \text{ if } |t| \geq 1 \\ (t, e^{-\frac{1}{1-t^2}})  & \text{ if } |t| < 1 \end{cases} $$
It is $C^{\infty}$ and agrees with the curve $\alpha(t) = (t,0)$ on two disjoint unbounded intervals.
Since you want $\gamma$ to be the image curve under a diffeomorphism I suggest the diffeomorphism
$$ \phi : (x,y) \rightarrow \begin{cases} (x,y) & \text{ if } |x| \geq 1 \\ \left(x,y+e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}} \right) & \text{ if } |x| < 1 \end{cases}. $$
Which has the inverse
$$ \phi^{-1} : (u,v) \rightarrow \begin{cases} (u,v) & \text{ if } |u| \geq 1 \\ \left(u,v-e^{-\frac{1}{1-u^2}} \right) & \text{ if } |u| < 1 \end{cases}. $$
And consider the curve $\phi(t,0)$ which gives you $\gamma$. 
 
**EDIT:** 
Define the intersection set $$ X=\{ (s,t) \in ]a,b[ \times [0,1] | \alpha(s) = \gamma(t) \}. $$
Firstly it is closed: 
Take $(s_n,t_n) \rightarrow (s,t)$ a converging sequence in $X$. Then $$ \alpha(s) = \lim_n \alpha_n(s_n) = \lim_n \gamma(t_n) = \gamma(t). $$
This shows $(s,t) \in X$, hence $X$ is closed. 
Secondly the values $t$ can take is clearly bounded since it is a subset of $[0,1]$. 
 
Lastly the values $s$ can take is bounded since if we write $\alpha = (\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ we have
$$ X = \{ (s,t) \in ]a,b[ \times [0,1] | \alpha_1(s) = \gamma_1(t) \} \cap \{ (s,t) \in ]a,b[ \times [0,1] | \alpha_2(s) = \gamma_2(t) \}. $$
Now if $\alpha$ is not a point, then at one of the $\alpha_i$'s is invertible. Assume w.l.o.g. we can take $\alpha_1$. Write $\alpha_1(s) = zt+w$. Then 
$$ \{ (s,t) \in ]a,b[ \times [0,1] | \alpha_1(s) = \gamma_1(t) \} = \{ (s,t) \in ]a,b[ \times [0,1] | s = \gamma_1(t)/z-w/z \}.$$
The values $s$ achieves in this set is then given by the continuous image of $\gamma_1(t)/z-w/z$ under $[0,1]$. Hence it is compact and hence bounded. 
So $X$ is written as the intersection of two sets of which one is certainly bounded. Combining this with the closedness of $X$, we conclude it is compact.

Comment: while this is true, for $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow...$, it is not an counterexample for $\gamma$ with a compact support. (or i am missing something)

Comment: yea... i suck at not forgetting something in the question. you've answered my question, so ill accept yours, but do you know, if this holds, for paths with compact support?

Comment: How do you then define compact intersection? Do you mean that you have two curves $\alpha: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, and $\gamma: ]a,b[ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and that the values $t \in ]a,b[$ such that $\gamma(t) = \alpha(t)$  must combine to a compact set? 
That's automatically since $t$ must belong to $[0,1]$.

Comment: No they mustnt combine to a compact set. what matters is, that $supp(\alpha)$ is compact.

Comment: Oh srry, my mistake. What I meant was that in the case of my comment it is always true that the $t$'s making the intersection form a compact set.

Comment: but i completly fail to see, why. Once it is compact, then yes, i would agree, that the intersections are of the finite nature i desire. But i dont understand the step, that this set IS compact

Comment: Oh sorry I was again mistaken in the comments, what I defined to be the intersection is the set $\{ t \in ]a,b[ \cap [0,1] | \alpha(t) = \gamma(t) \}$. But that's wrong since intersections don't in general happen for the same $t$ in both curves. Could you state your definition of the intersection set (which we want to be not a compact interval)?

Comment: The set $\{(s,t)\in]a,b[\times[0,1]|\alpha(s)=\gamma(t)\}$, and then it should be enough, to just look at the first coordinates, of this set, because from $s$, follows a unique $t$, since diffeomorphism, and viceversa, from $t$ follows a unique $s$.

Comment: That's not in general true if $\gamma$ is not injective, but I think when looking at the two coordinates it gives a reasonable definition. But since $[01]$ is compact it's image under a diffeomorphism is compact. Since $\alpha$ is linear, it's relation can be inverted to a continuous map on that compact set. Which shows the values of $s \in ]a,b[$ in the intersection set is compact

Comment: The set is also closed, since if $(s_n,t_n) \rightarrow (s,t)$ is a converging sequence in the intersection, then $\alpha(s) = \lim_n \alpha(s_n) = \lim_n \gamma(t_n) = \gamma(t)$ hence $(s,t)$ belongs to the intersection. Since the values of $s$ and $t$ remains bounded (see my previous comment), and the set is closed it is compact.

Comment: but $\gamma$ is injective, since its a linear function composed with a diffeomorphism. Also wouldnt this already require the set of intersections to be compact, since you are creating the continuous function, which is by default only defined on the set of intersections? Ah ok. with your second comment it all comes to an end. closed + bounded is what i was failing to see. thank you very, very much

Comment: and just, to bring it full circle, compact implies a finite covering, and therefore consisting of only finitly many closed intervals right?

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot. Indeed I was a bit sloppy there
You can look at the set $\{ s \in ]a,b[ | \exists t \in [0,1]: \alpha(s) = \gamma(t) \}$ as the intersection of $\{ s \in ]a,b[ | \exists t \in [0,1]: \alpha_i(s) = \gamma_i(t) \}$ over the coordinates (write $\alpha(s) = \alpha_1(s), \alpha_2(s))$. At least one of those sets is bounded otherwise the curve $\alpha$ would just be a constant and then indeed the set is not compact. But this is non-interesting case. Since at least one of the sets in the intersection is bounded, the intersection set is bounded. By the closedness it is also compact.

Comment: In the previous comment I meant $\{ s \in ]a,b[ | \exists t \in [0,1]: \alpha(s) = \gamma(t) \} = \cap_i \{ s \in ]a,b[ | \exists t \in [0,1]: \alpha_i(s) = \gamma_i(t) \}$. And yes about the finite covering, that is true.

Comment: didnt you now show the closedness twice? first time with the limes? and boundedness is inherent, since $[0,1]$ is the maximum for this set, which is certainly bounded?

Comment: anyways, i certainly appreciate your time. thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe I can better sumarize things in my answer. No problem Jacobus Conradi.

Comment: I'm kind of having second doubts. where exactly did your/our proof need, that $\gamma$ needs to be $C^\infty$-diffeom.? because if we dont use it, we could use this, to show, that some weird function like $f(x) = x*sin(1/x)$ only intersects the x,axist between 0 and 1 infinitly many times.

Comment: I guess our proof is correct for $\gamma$ continuous, however we required that $\gamma$ is determined only on a compact interval. If $\gamma$ was defined on an unbounded interval things can go wrong like my example.

Comment: but in my example $f(x)$ is fully definied on $[0,1]$, and continuous. and the other function $\gamma(t) = 0$ is continuous as well and again fully definied on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @JacobusConradi  That curve is indeed $C^{\infty}$, you can prove it based on induction on order of differentiability  but you need to do a lot of calculation, which is really pain. The BIGGEST problem is that this is NOT a counterexample, this is indeed an example that confirms your claim!  since intersection is $ (-\infty, -1] \cup [1, + \infty)$

Comment: Haha.The mistake is in the 'full circle'-comment. The zero set is compact however it is not a finite union of closed intervals. I think the problem is harder than it seems since for every $n$ you can construct a $C^n$-function $f_n(x) = x^n sin(1/x)$ which has that property.

Comment: @abcdef so we didnt show a thing... hurray

Comment: Well we did show it is compact :) That was the question at the beginning. But indeed we were dragged of in too many interesting things.

Comment: @adcdef of course we showed something, but not quiet what i needed hehe

Comment: Even for $C^{\infty}$ curves it may fail if we take $f(x) = e^{-1/x^2} .sin(1/x)$.

Comment: Yeah, that's too bad. I guess we had some fun in the search of it.

Comment: @abcdef $sin(1/x)$ is not quiet $C^\infty$, oh wait that is a multiplication dot. nevermind

Comment: That's why I added the factor $e^{-1/x^2}$, the point in between denotes the multiplication (I didn't meant coordinates).

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong; Take $P_1 = (1,0) , P_2=(0,0)$

Then  $\gamma_1(t)=tP_1+(1-t)P_2 = (t,0)$.

Define $\Phi(\alpha, \beta) = (\alpha, sin(\alpha)+\beta).$ Therefore

$$  \gamma_2(t)= \Phi (\gamma_1(t)) = (t,sin(t))$$

Which crosses $X-axis$ infinitely countable many times.

Comment: Indeed that's also correct. The intersection set can be unbounded and not discrete (my answer) and unbounded and discrete (your answer).

Comment: @abcdef   Yes .  My example shows that the intersection is unbounded and DISCRETE. so it rejects the claim in question...

But in your answer you must prove that the intersection can't be written as a finite union of closed interval !